# Error: tools:replace specified at line:9 for attribute android:appComponentFactory,

Tags: android

I am new to the android studio and following a series of video lectures led me to those issues. May someone help me sort this out?

[image: Merged manifest]

Text Manifest

[image: Text Manifest]

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext. [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Please provide the actual code instead of just plain screen shots. Even the screen shot of you manifest file is not complete.

Comment: @ankuranurag2  anything else?